# Put body of \descript on same line as header

Tags: fonts, resume

I'm using a resume template in overleaf and I like the font that comes with \descript. But, is there a way for my languages and tools to be the same line as the header? (as opposed to underneath)

```
\descript{Languages \& Tools:} 
Python, C/C++, JavaScript, HTML/CSS, Java, SQL, Bash, Docker, Grafana, VHDL
```

[image: how it looks on resume]

Comment: Further, if I add another \descript{header} afterwards, is there a way for 'header' to be on a new line? It is currently hanging off '... Grafana, VHDL'

Comment: Welcome! There are lots of templates on Overleaf and answering the question in its current form is impossible.